# How to open data roaming setting in dual sim android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-settings, data-connections

By this code:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
context.startActivity(i);
```

I am able to open the data roaming setting activity successfully. Lets have a look at the screenshot:

[image]

When I click on the Data Connection it prompt me like this way:

[image]

because my phone is dual sim. Now I want to open the prompt window without clicking the data connection. Is it possible? Can I open the window(Second picture) directly?

Answer (score 1):

Dual SIM support is part of AOSP since Android 5.1 (SKD22), so all previous versions feature vendors' extension, which means it is not standarized.
See: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html

Comment: Some days ago I have used Java Reflection to get information whether the phone is dual sim or not and it is working very nicely for all SDK. So I thought it also may be solvable.